# Running yii2 application pulled from gitlab won't work

Tags: php, git, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have an issue running my Yii2 application.It works fine on my computer i.e. localhost but when pulled from the git lab it is not running.The error is-

```
An Error occurred while handling another error exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/error' in  /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:127 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(95): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#2 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#4 {main} Previous exception: exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to    resolve the request: site/' in   /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:127 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102):   yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/jd4test/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#4 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not  found.' in  /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:114 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/jd4test/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/jd4test/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

now there have been some changes after the state it was working on local host as in rules added in the web.php config file-

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    ],
```

also an .htaccess file is added,

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

plz help me out,the project is working fine without this,but consider that this adding of other files and codes that i pasted here is kind of necessary.How should i go about it?

Comment: Try to set the default or the catchAll route and test it. Can the web server resolve the route and is working accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says `invalidRouteException`. Check your urls and make sure you have pulled it correctly to the shared host from git.

Comment: does it have anything to do with the rules that I mentioned?

Comment: I dont think so. The problem shouldnt have anything to do with rules or you .htaccess file. Try checking the changes in your shared host